# PHP memcached for Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: php, memcached

How to install memcached in windows XP 32 bit ?

I could install memcache successfully and can use using the below code

```
$m = new Memcache;
$m->connect('localhost',11211);
```

But I need to work with memcached like this,

```
$m = new Memcached();
$servers = array(
    array('localhost', 11211)
    );
    $m->addServers($servers);
```

Now the above code is showing Memcached class not found. Since its not installed.
So how can I install memcached in windows XP 32 bit

Comment: Seems memcached is not available in Windows so far. I am using virtual box with linux. My suggession is use either virtual box or linux itself to work with memcached.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and for those that don't want to (or can't, for whatever reason) run a virtual machine, I ended up having different code for running on windows vs running on linux.

When I ran the following:

```
$m = new Memcache;
print_r(get_class_methods($m));
```

I noticed that `Memcache` doesn't have an `AddServers()` method, that's something for `Memcached` (see [php.net docs on Memcache class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) compared to the [php.net docs on Memcached class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.memcached.php) and notice there is a *lot* more to `Memcached`!).

So for Windows (where you need to use `Memcache`, no `Memcached` available), the solution is to create your own short loop for adding multiple servers:

```
$m = new Memcache();
$servers = array(
    array('localhost', 11211),
    // ... other servers here
);
foreach ($servers as $s) $m->addServer($s[0], $s[1]);
```

If you need to have both sets of code for Windows and Linux available, you can always just enclose the above in `if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT')` and put your Linux code in an else statement after it. So, something similar to:

```
$servers = array(
    array('localhost', 11211),
    // ... other servers here
);
if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT') {
    $m = new Memcache();
    foreach ($servers as $s) $m->addServer($s[0], $s[1]);
}
else {
    $m = new Memcached();
    $m->addServers($servers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

having the same problem as you.

And after reading http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/ , i found out that the Memcached is designed for linux due to libmemcached.

Still waiting for the proper solution about this problem.

Is there anyone who can help us? thank you.

*sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Better option is. Use Oracle virtual box with linux or Linux OS itself.